# The implementations of the "Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm" (UAX#14)

Tags: unicode, implementation

I've been searching around to find a latest implementation of the [*Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm (UAX#14)*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/) to port it for my needs.

I've found an [old](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-24.html), but seemingly *normative* [sample implementation](https://github.com/behnam/unicode-line-break-sample-cpp) of the algorithm, in which a *"Pair Table-Based Implementation"* is utilized. The implementation cited the [corresponding section](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-24.html#PairBasedImplementation) of the old document that is deleted [starting from Unicode 10.0](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-39.html#PairBasedImplementation). So,

- Why the ["§7: Pair Table-Based Implementation"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-39.html#PairBasedImplementation) is deleted and what are the alternatives?
- Are there any public and full-implementations to the latest version of the algorithm, or at-least to the last version of the algorithm  in which the *"Pair Table-Based Implementation"* was still around (in [Unicode 9.0](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-37.html#PairBasedImplementation))?

Answer (score 2):

The latest official line breakers implementations for #14 and #29 are included in the Rust crate [`icu_segmenter`](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu4x/tree/64c3859ae91ab7881c3f8161f0f200daba7438f2/experimental/segmenter) maintained by the Unicode organization. See the API docs at https://unicode-org.github.io/icu4x-docs/doc/icu_segmenter/

Comment: You probably want this URL now:
https://docs.rs/icu/latest/icu/segmenter/index.html , the other is 404

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in JavaScript: [linebreak](https://github.com/foliojs/linebreak)

Comment: That one is also based on the pair table